# need to sum only specific sub-groups in Crystal report. sub group formula

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

I have a report that is grouped by job number(5 characters) then account number(4 characters) then sub account number(2 characters). at the bottom of each job number group I need to show the sum of all the account numbers that start with a 7 then a sum of all the other account numbers. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a formula field and sum it in the sub report

named "seven"

```
if left(totext(table.accountnumber,0,""),1)="7" then tableamountfield else 0
```